# How append a string in a file text on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string, file, append

Hello i want to put some text string at the end of my file log, locate in the sd external, but didnt works.

```
public boolean saveLog(String data){
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt", true));
            bw.write(data);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
            bw.close();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This solutions works for me:

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/log.txt", true));
```

Comment: your file path does not seems to be correct.. not pointing to external storage

Comment: you are right, this works... thanks @JonnathanQ

new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/log.txt", true));